# Changing ViewController if user is Facebook Logged in

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, facebook, uiviewcontroller

I'm having quite some troubles implementing Facebook login in my iOS , everything works fine if the user is not already logged in, the application fetches correctly the data from Facebook and pass them to the next ViewController , instead if is already logged in it should automatically segue to a recap page that shows user's info but i can't make it happen, currently I'm using this method :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        LoginButton.delegate = self

        if (FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil) {

            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Login", sender: self)
        }
    }
```

but in the console i get :

Facebook_Login.LoginViewController: 0x7fc04a519ca0 on Facebook_Login.ViewController: 0x7fc04a41c1e0 whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

i've also tried using the viewdidAppear method, but it segues to the recap page without updating the variables so i get an empty page

here' the complete code:

View Controller 1

import UIKit
import FBSDKLoginKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {

```
var nome1:String = ""
var cognome1:String = ""
var email1:String = ""
var compleanno:String = ""
var città:String = ""
var genere:String = ""
var immagine_url:String = ""

@IBOutlet weak var LoginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!

@IBAction func LoginAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    LoginButton.delegate = self
    LoginButton.readPermissions = ["email"]


}

func FetchInfo(){

    print("scarico le informazioni...")

    let parametri = ["fields":"email, first_name, last_name, birthday, hometown, gender, picture.type(large)"]

    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: parametri).startWithCompletionHandler{(connection,result,error) -> Void in

        if (error != nil){

            print ("errore")
            return
        }

        else {

            if let email = result["email"] as? String {

                print(email)
                self.email1 = email
            }

            if let nome = result["first_name"] as? String {

                print(nome)
                self.nome1 = nome
            }

            if let cognome = result["last_name"] as? String {

                print(cognome)
                self.cognome1 = cognome
            }

            if let compleanno = result["birthday"] as? String{

                print(compleanno)
            }

            if let città = result["hometown"] as? String{

                print(città)
            }

            if var genere = result["gender"] as? String{

                if (genere == "male"){

                    genere = "maschio" 
                }

                else {

                    genere = "femmina"
                }

                print(genere)
            }
        }

        if let picture = result["picture"] as? NSDictionary, data = picture["data"] as? NSDictionary, url = data["url"] as? String{

            self.immagine_url = url
            print(self.immagine_url)


        }

    }

    return
}


func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!){

    if (result.isCancelled == true){
        print("cancellato")
    }

    else {

        print("login effettuato")
        FetchInfo()
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Login", sender: self)
    }

}

func loginButtonDidLogOut(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!){

}

func loginButtonWillLogin(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) -> Bool{

    return true
}



@IBAction func returned(segue:UIStoryboardSegue){

}



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    LoginButton.delegate = self

}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    if (FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil) {

        FetchInfo()
        if(nome1 == ""){


                        }

        else {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Login", sender: self)
        }
    }


}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    let destinazione:LoginViewController = segue.destinationViewController
    as! LoginViewController

    destinazione.temp_nome = nome1
    destinazione.temp_cognome = cognome1
    destinazione.temp_email = email1
    destinazione.img_profile_url = immagine_url


}
```

}

ViewController 2:

import UIKit
import FBSDKLoginKit

class LoginViewController: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {

```
var temp_nome = ""
var temp_cognome = ""
var temp_email = ""
var img_profile_url:String = ""


@IBOutlet weak var Nome_Utente: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var email: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var Immagine_Utente: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var Login_button: FBSDKLoginButton!

@IBAction func Login_button_Action(sender: AnyObject) {

    Login_button.delegate = self
}


func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!){

}

func loginButtonDidLogOut(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!){

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Back", sender: self)
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Nome_Utente.text = "\(temp_nome)" + " " + "\(temp_cognome)"
    email.text = "\(temp_email)"


}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Comment: Are you sure to update informations correctly ? Where, in your recap view, do you update your UI items with the user's informations ?

Comment: Yes absolutely , If I click on the login button everything works fine... if it's helpful I can upload the complete code

Comment: You can, it is always easier to figure out what's wrong ;)

Comment: Done , is in italian so if you need help just ask :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, avoid to reset your `LoginButton.delegate` in the `LoginAction()` function.

If the user is already logged in, to avoid an useless call to the Facebook Graph API (if you do not necessarily need to update his informations), you can store your user informations in **CoreData** or in a **NSUserDefault**.

If you never used it you can use the CDHelper lib ([CoreDataHelper](https://github.com/lobodart/CoreDataHelper)) which will allow you to use it without difficulties.

Hope I was helpful, if not, do not hesitate to give us a feedback.

Btw, in your `viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)` function, you have to call `super.viewDidAppear(animated)` !

Comment: You are 100% right , btw I never used the core data , what are they're purpose ?

Comment: Okay, CoreData is one of the different ways to store some data in the device. You have to configure your project to allow it to use CoreData, all is explained on the [Apple Developper Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html), and the library mentioned on my answer is very helpful !

Comment: Ok I got it, you suggest to log in the user, fetch the info , store them in the core data , then segue to the second view controller and read the info form core data without the preparerSegue method?

Comment: Exactly, it is a good way to allow user to use your application without network, and keep his informations to use it everywhere in your application in anytime. The only "bad" point is that (I think) you do not have real time informations, I mean if the user change his profile picture, it will not be changed in your App.